Either this OR that and the Unsaid!
I am reading logic and in it I am reading OR, so comes along this Sentence,
Either this or that, (for an Expression pVq).
So currently we are in the Logic universe where hardly anything exists, except for true, false, negation, and and or. So now in that Universe when I come across a reference "this", Please tell me WHAT is it Pointing TO?! My hunch is that it is pointing to True, by default. The English language word "this" in this context is pointing to True, WITHOUT EXPLICITELY saying it. See this "Unsaid" and "Implicit" in the Language and Conversation is Troubling me ever since I started studying Logic.
Similarly See this Statement "Either this or that" also feels incomplete, "either this or that" for What?! In my opinion the correct full Statement is "Either this or that, for the whole expression to be true". Language and also the way it is spoken seems to Favour True.
See I am studying Logic for Quite some time now and I always feel that in Logic, "What is" is slightly different from what is explained and it makes a lot of difference in Understanding the topic and to be able to see the full implications/picture. I see it like this
"Either this or that": pVr
"Either this or that for the Expression to be True":pVr=True
One is Expression vs One is Equation.
My Question is, Is my thinking correct? You may or may not see the importance in the difference, but do you concur with me that there is a difference. I am going into so much detail because one day I plan to teach kids so I NEED TO KNOW WHAT'S CORRECT...

I assume it means either this truth value or some other truth value where the understood phrase is truth value.

@mdewey if what you are saying is True then I have been reading Logic wrong all my life. I seriously think it' True, it can't be "Truth value". Either Truth Value OR Truth Value, nah can't digest it...

As far as I know, $p \vee q$ means "this" OR "that" OR BOTH.

I’m voting to close this question because This question is off-topic because it is a mathematical question as contrasted with a question about mathematics education. For a Stack Exchange site for mathematical questions please see Mathematics.

I suggest thinking of the $p$ and $q$ in the expression $p \vee q$ as standing in for unknown statements in much the same way that you might be used to thinking of $x$ as standing in for an unknown number.
For instance if $p$ is the statement "I can bench press 315 pounds" and $q$ is the statement "I can squat 315 pounds" then $p \vee q$ would stand for the statement "I can either bench press or squat 315 pounds (or both)".
I can see the following benefits of learning a little bit of formal logic for teaching at the pre-college level:

It will help you to be clear about what you mean when you say things like "$(x-1)(x-2) = 0$ if and only if $x=1$ or $x=2$" to your students.  I don't recommend teaching 13 year olds how to deal with formal expressions like $p \Longleftrightarrow q \vee r$, but if you are comfortable with such things it could lead you to be more precise with your reasoning when you teach them algebra and geometry.
It is becoming more common to have some computer programming in the pre-college curriculum.  Sometimes this is being integrated into mathematics classes.  It is necessary to understand how to work with negation, disjunction, and conjunction operators on boolean (true/false) values to write even very simple programs.  Consider this program for instance:

for i in range(20):
    if (i%2 == 0) or (i%3 == 0):
        print(i)

To understand how this program will behave, one needs to understand what will happen when $i = 1$, $i = 2$, $i=3$, and $i=6$ are plugged into the boolean expression (i%2 == 0) or (i%3 == 0).  Each of these cases corresponds to a distinct row of the truth table for or.

Thanks for the Answer, Steve. I am very far away from "teaching" anything I am not absolutely sure about. See it's for understanding. You will never understand the problem when one has to read higher order complicated things in "non mother tongue" language. It's just not quite the same. So also one of the things I am interested in is the understanding itself. So when I don't understand something and then after few days I understand it, I spend hours analysing my mind. Why do I understand it now?! What changed within?! Hence language becomes important.

The thing is Mathematics happened suddenly to me, I became interested in knowing, when a computer sees me, what does it see. So I am in the land of Axioms for many months now so my mind is in Axiom mode, so if you start talking about "bench press" or pound, in my mind I am like dude I dont understand bench press or whatever, I just know, True, False, Negation, And and Or and English Language, can you explain it to me within that. That taking those Logical Equations to the "real world" is another beast I have to tackle because from "pVr" to real world application a whole world gets dropped...

@AshishShukla I think that you are putting yourself in a very common self-limiting trap.  People studying symbolic logic often mislead themselves into thinking that it is somehow circular to apply ordinary reasoning to the study of formal logical systems.  This is not so.  The formal logical systems are ordinary objects of mathematics, like any other.  The way we understand them is through (ordinary) logical arguments, analogies, visualizations, intuitions, etc.

I understand that we'll use simple statements to explain something but I was hoping it would be possible to explain with very limited set of things.
